# Buddypress in Thesis Theme

Tags: buddypress

Does anyone more brilliant than me know how to install Buddypress on the Wordpress Thesis Theme Framework. :D Thanks everyone!

J Winton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Thesis isn't compatible with Buddypress. We tried a while ago and ended up going for a theme that works with BP out of the box. (Currently, we're using DynamiX on one of our sites: http://themeforest.net/item/dynamix-premium-wordpress-theme/113901)

HTH